# SharePoint Online press Button and wait until setState variable has been updated

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, react

I have a Button. This will be clicked and get the value of a counter. This counter values are set to the state variable. After that I want to update the counter with a new number. My problem is that the state variable is not updated in time when I wanted to update the counter.

How can I wait until the state variables are updated?

Here is my code so far:

At first I click the Button:

```
<div><PrimaryButton text="Create Update and TS Item" onClick={()=>this.CreateAndUpdateTS()}/></div>
```

Then I call another function which get the values of the counter:

```
private CreateAndUpdateTS(){

     this.getCounterValue()
      
  

    console.log("NewID: "+this.state.counterOldID);
    console.log("ID: "+this.state.counterID);

    let TSID = this.state.counterID;
    console.log("ID 2: "+TSID);

    let counterAdd =1;
    let counterOld = this.state.counterOldID;
    let counterNew = counterOld + counterAdd;
    console.log("ID"+ this.state.counterID +" CounterNew"+counterNew);

    this._spDataProvider.CounterUpdate("Counter",this.state.counterID,counterNew);

  }
```

But I always get the wrong values after I called `this.counterValue()`. I need to wait until the state is updated. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you get correct values at these lines? `console.log("NewID: "+this.state.counterOldID);
    console.log("ID: "+this.state.counterID);`

Comment: Also, you can pass callback function to setState as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401635/how-can-i-wait-for-setstate-to-finish-before-triggering-a-function-in-react. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No, I didn't get the correct values. useEffect is not working in my case.

Comment: You don't have to use the `useEffect`. you can pass callback function to setState. check my answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private CreateAndUpdateTS(){
    this.getCounterValue()
}

private getCounterValue(): void {
    this._spDataProvider.ReadCounterValue("Counter").then((items)=>{  
        console.log("Counter Value: "+ JSON.stringify(items))
        console.log(items[0].NewId);
        this.setState(
            {
                counterID: items[0].NewId
            },
            this.updateCounterValue // your callback function
        )
    })
}

private updateCounterValue(): void {
    console.log("ID: " + this.state.counterID);

    let counterAdd = 1;
    let counterOld = this.state.counterID;
    let counterNew = counterOld + counterAdd;

    this._spDataProvider.CounterUpdate("Counter", this.state.counterID, counterNew);
}
```

**Reference**: [How can I wait for setState to finish before triggering a function in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37401726)